# Set connection string of an event hub for azure function with CI/CD

Tags: c#, azure, azure-devops, azure-functions, cicd

I'm deploying an azure function triggered by an event hub with CI/CD on azure devops.
When I deploy it manually on Visual Studio the connection string is correctly configured so the azure function is triggered. But when I do it with CI/CD the connection string is missing so the azure function is not triggered.
I tried to put this connection string in appsettings file, in the pipeline variable etc... nothing works.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Is the appsettings file making it into the repo in Devops? You can always [configure function app settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-use-azure-function-app-settings?tabs=portal) directly on the portal but this is a potentially undesirable manual step.

Comment: yes it is in the repo. Oh ok I'll check that option thx

Answer (score 0):

In Azure DevOps, you can set the EventHub connection string in **Function App App task -> Application and Configuration Settings ->App settings** .

For example:

[image]

You can also add other app settings configuration here. When you deploy the Function APP on CD pipeline, these configurations will be deployed to the App settings of the Function App at the same time.

Here is a doc about [Function App Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-function-app?view=azure-devops).

Comment: Yes thank you I did this in order to deploy it.
Thanks for your help all

Comment: if the answer can help you ，you may consider accepting it thanks